# Angular ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush not getting triggered on input change

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have a simple component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-person-table',
    templateUrl: './person-table.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./person-table.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class PersonTableComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    @Input() result: PageResult<Person>;

    public personsSub: Subscription;

    constructor(public personsStore: PersonsStore, public routerStore: RouterStore, public stringService: StringService) {
        this.personsSub = this.personsStore.getResult().subscribe(result => {
            this.result = result;
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.personsSub.unsubscribe();
    }

    goToPerson(person: Person) {
        if (person) {
            this.routerStore.go(['persons', person.id]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my template I simply do

```
<div class="table" *ngIf="result?.data && result.data.length > 0">
    <div class="row header">
        Header
    </div>
    <div class="row filters">
        Filter
    </div>
    <ng-template ngFor let-row [ngForOf]="result.data" let-i="index">
        <div class="row data" >
            Row #{{ i }}
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

At first result is `null` but then it receives a real `PageResult` object. If I comment out `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` the template renders fine. If I leave `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` active, the template is blank.

Can someone explain to me why changing the `result` variable doesn't trigger the change detection mechanism?

Comment: Change should come from parent component

Comment: OnPush means: trigger change detection only when the parent component changes the value of one of the inputs, i.e. passes a different value as input to the component. That's not the case here, and result shouldn't be decorated with Input, since it's not actually one.